# When I load the developer console, I get a "Total Requests Limit Exceeded" error

Tags: apex, unit-test, limits, developer-console

When I load the developer console, I get a "Total Requests Limit Exceeded" error. This is on a dev org. I have been using the Force.com IDE all day, and have been writing a lot of unit tests (and running a lot of unit tests). What is going on here?

[image: obnoxious picture of error message]

> REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
>
> Error querying for trace flag: TotalRequests Limit exceeded.
>
> [OK]

Comment: Lol (working too hard). At times like these I abandon the dev console and use the old web based interface for 24hrs

Comment: I'm thinking you've run over your API request limit, since the Dev Console consumes API requests. There was also a recent post about how to limit calls here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/how-to-limit-api-calls-when-using-the-developer-console

Comment: Try calling Salesforce Support and create a new ticket.  Ask to get your API Limits increased temporarily.  SF-Support is generally friendly and will grant the request

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It sounds like you've ran into your API Limit for the 24-period.

Check this.  Go to <kbd>Setup</kbd> and then click `System Overview`

You API Usage will be on the top right.  If you are at your maximum, I suggest calling Salesforce-Support immediately, and ask to get your API Limits increased temporarily. SF-Support is generally friendly and will usually grant the request.  (If you have 5,000 API calls/day, ask for an increase to 10,000 temporarily).

Screen shot of `System Overview` Link:

[image: Where the 'System Overview' link is located]

[image: API Limits in the System Overview page]

Comment: yeah, that's it. I had no idea that the developer console uses the api. Seems weird that it would since it appears to be in the SF ecosystem. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Yea, I agree.  I can run through ~4,000 API calls with just me on the Dev console continuously for 8 hours.  And with two developers on the DevConsole, the usage runs twice as fast.  :/  But there are no API calls using the Visualforce editor

Comment: Anyone know what phone number I need to call?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/  click "Contact Support"

Comment: FYI, If you use a Partner Portal provisioned DE org you get 10,000 by default.