# How Salesforce developer console can consume API REQUEST?

Tags: community, metadata-api, salesforce-id

I wonder how Salesforce developer console can consume API request. Let me explain in detail.

There are no schedule classes in my org,nothing is scheduled. I checked System overview the API REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS is 0, then i just opened developer console the API REQUESTS LAST 24 HOURS is 8, then i run a test class API REQUESTS LAST 24 HOURS is 20 then, i ran all test classes in the org now the API REQUESTS, LAST 24 HOURS is 800. I repeat this procedure 8-10 times my API LIMIT got exceeded. I can't even open developer console, can't login to trailhead, can't login from workbench. Why Salesforce counts developer console in API request despite i am not calling to any external system?

Answer (score 2):

It uses the tooling API to communicate with SF, so it consumes API requests. This once tricked me into thinking that outbound API calls count against your limit - they don't, but I was firing them by using the developer console, so that was using API calls itself.

See this question about limiting the developer console's API usage:

[How to limit API calls when using the Developer Console?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24747/how-to-limit-api-calls-when-using-the-developer-console)

And consider switching to a IDE on your local machine. There are many advantages to using Illuminated Cloud, Welkin Suite, or VS Code.

Comment: My concern is, it's sales force own tool, so it shouldn't count the limit.

Comment: Sadly, though, it is what it is. And it's been that way for years. I don't think there's much chance of it changing